# regexp for not allowing special characters at the end/start but should allow spaces

Tags: javascript

how to create  regular expression for not allowing special characters at the begining and at the end, but it should allow white spaces anywhere. i have tried /^a-zA-Z0-9?$/   , but not allowing spaces at the end/start. if i use /^a-zA-Z0-9?$/ it is allowing special characters also.thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe what spl (special?) characters are in your case and describe how many characters at the beginning and end should be excluded from being special

Comment: @mvermand Assuming, from what he's tried, he just wants to block anything but a-z (and capitalized), and 0-9. Everything else isn't allowed.

Comment: Based on your reading of the regexp documentation, what do you think `/^a-zA-Z0-9?$/` means?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[ a-zA-Z0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9 ])?$
```

This regex will restrict leading and trailing special characters but allows space's.

Answer (score 0):

This regex accepts any line starting and ending with any alphanumeric character or a space:

`^(\w| ).*(\w| )$`

Note that `\w` is equals to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/SDz8pL/1) you can find a little example.